Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor'
Context:
I'm facing an error while deploying the shade jar on lambda. The jar was is working on Spring Boot 2.6.8 but not on Spring Boot 2.7.18.
Error:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeclarePrecedence not presently supported in Spring AOP

Stacktrace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeclarePrecedence not presently supported in Spring AOP
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:575)
  at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
  at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
  at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:195)
  at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.AsyncInitializationWrapper$AsyncInitializer.run(AsyncInitializationWrapper.java:118)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeclarePrecedence not presently supported in Spring AOP
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:405)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:255)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1135)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
  ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeclarePrecedence not presently supported in Spring AOP
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AspectMetadata.<init>(AspectMetadata.java:98)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:106)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:255)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1135)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
  ... 36 common frames omitted

pom.xml
My pom.xml is too large that I can't paste all here, however some of the important dependencies are:
<properties>
     <datadog.version>1.9.17</datadog.version>
<properties>

<!-- ... -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-datadog</artifactId>
    <version>${datadog.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>

I've read below answers but none of them were useful for me:

Spring Boot deploy fail - Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' is thrown on adding eureka server to spring boot Applicatio
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.orm.jpa.HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration

Any help would be really appreciable!

Please provide an MCVE on GitHub, reproducing the problem. Debugging invisible code is somewhat difficult. Probably, you will not get more than educated guesses like the following: The error message "DeclarePrecedence not presently supported in Spring AOP" implies that a native AspectJ aspect using a @DeclarePrecedence annotation is somehow tried to be used as a Spring AOP aspect. Whyever this happens, it is a mistake, possibly a misconfiguration.
